# Replace text surrounded by specific characters

Tags: regex, perl, replace, sed, awk

I have this type of data (all big letters are strings)

```
>A|B|C|D|E|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|C|D|E|F
test test test
test
```

and want to delete C, D, E:

```
>A|B|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|F
test test test
test
```

In "test" text, no `|` occurs. I have tried this with `sed`, but Im not able to replace the text which comes after two `|`
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So in your real data you have multi-character fields and you do not have "|"s separating the fields, correct? Maybe it'd be useful for you to post sample input and expected output that reflects that then, rather than single-character fields separated by "|"s. Just throwin' it out there...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Generalised sample input is may be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl oneliner,

```
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print /\|/ ? join "|", @F[0,1,5] : $_' file
```

it splits every line by `|` char and store values in `@F` array. If line contains `|` it takes elements 0,1, and 5 from @F, otherwise leaves line as it is.

Oneliner deparsed,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -F'\|' -lane 'print /\|/ ? join "|", @F[0,1,5] : $_' file
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }         # -l switch makes print to add newline
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {    # -n switch
    chomp $_;                           # -l switch chomps newlines
    our(@F) = split(/\|/, $_, 0);       # -a switch splits on value of -F switch
    print /\|/ ? join('|', @F[0, 1, 5]) : $_;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
>A|B|C|D|E|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|C|D|E|F
test test test
test
>gene_8|GeneMark.hmm|322_aa|+|3803|4771TS28_contig03869
test test test
test test
$
$ sed -r 's/(([^|]+\|){2})(([^|]+\|){3})/\1/' file
>A|B|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|F
test test test
test
>gene_8|GeneMark.hmm|4771TS28_contig03869
test test test
test test
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` works fine:

```
$ cat 1
>A|B|C|D|E|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|C|D|E|F
test test test
test
$ sed 's/C|D|E|//' 1
>A|B|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|F
test test test
test
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
$ sed  's/\([^|]|[^|]|\).*|/\1/' 1
>A|B|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|F
test test test
test
```

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. A, B, C, D, E, F are strings. A example is: `>gene_8|GeneMark.hmm|322_aa|+|3803|4771TS28_contig03869`. I want to delete the content independenly from the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) is suited to this

```
awk --re-interval -F'|'\
      'NF > 4{$0=gensub(/^(([^|]*\|){2})([^|]*\|){3}(.*)$/, "\\1\\4", -1)};
      {print}' file
```

Comment: FYI you only need `--re-interval` in older gawk releases, it's the default behavior in recent gawks (no, I don't know when that changed but it's been a while). Also, you don't need to set OFS as you're not re-compiling the record and you could just do `$0=gensub(...)` and lose the intermediate variable `z`.

Comment: @EdMorton, good points, incorporated. I am leaving the `--re-interval` in there because my version of GNU `awk` (3.1.8) seems to need it

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. The `-i` option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\|[CDE]//g' file
```

or using sed

```
sed -i.bak -re 's/\|[CDE]//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk works fine as well:

```
awk '{sub(/C\|D\|E\|/,"")}1' file
>A|B|F
test test test
test test
>A|B|F
test test test
test
```